# Multiple inserts using a single preparedStatement in a c++/mysql project

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I have a C++ project running on Linux and gcc/g++ 4.8. I am using MySql database version 5.7 and MySql C++ connector API 1.1.12. I am trying to execute two insert statements (each for a different table) separated by a semicolon. I got this working for *Statement*s but not for *PreparedStatement*s. See code sample below:

```
  #include "mysql_connection.h"
  #include <cppconn/driver.h>
  #include <cppconn/exception.h>
  #include <cppconn/resultset.h>
  #include <cppconn/statement.h>
  #include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>
  ....

  sql::Driver* driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  sql::ConnectOptionsMap options;
  options["hostName"] = "tcp://127.0.0.1";
  options["userName"] = "user";
  options["password"] = "password";
  options["schema"] = "test_db";
  options["port"] = 3306;
  options["CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS"] = true;

  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect(options);
```

Against that setup, I tried to run either of the following options:

```
  //option 1: works
  stmt = con->createStatement();
  stmt -> execute("INSERT INTO T_TEST1(TEST1) VALUES ('VALUE1');INSERT INTO T_TEST2(TEST2) VALUES ('VALUE2')");

  //option 2: does not work
  sql::PreparedStatement *pstmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO T_TEST1(TEST1) VALUES ('VALUE1');INSERT INTO T_TEST2(TEST2) VALUES ('VALUE2')");
  pstmt->executeUpdate();
```

Option 1 works. Option 2 but throws the following error:

```
# ERR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO T_TEST2(TEST2) VALUES ('TEST9')' at line 1 (MySQL error code: 1064, SQLState: 42000 )
```

Is there any way to make option 2 work?